# Creating indexOf function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create the indexOf function but it is not working. I am a noob programmer and started learning Javascript a few days ago.

I tried using loops but I don't think the concept of loops was clear with me. Can anyone please check the below code and help me understand what I did wrong and the correct usage of loops?

```js
function index(arr, srchvlu) {
  for (srchvlu = 0; srchvlu < arr.length; srchvlu = srchvlu + 1) {
    result = srchvlu;
  }
  return result;
}

var ans = (index("hello", "l"));

console.log(ans);
```

I expect the output to be 2 but the actual output is 4.

Comment: You need to use comparison to check values are equal or not, accordingly return the index, your code doesn't consider that

Comment: function index(arr, srchvlu) {
    return arr.indexOf(srchvlu)
}

let ans = (index([1,2,4], 4));
let ans1 = (index("hello", "o"));

console.log(ans, ans1);

Comment: Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: As I understand you want to know how loops work in any language but you have happend to choose javascript. The key to undersand is that a loop continues when a   condition is true. In your case when the counter is smaller than the length of the array it will continue.

Comment: For one, your code is overwriting the passed in search value with 0. You need to use a new variable as loop index. Next, you need to grab a single element from `arr`, your code doesn't even attempt to do that.

Comment: @FZs Implementing native methods is a good training method, you'll know what to expect as a result, the usage is well documented and they're often pretty simple to implement, but complex enough for beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test for equality of value and accordingly return the value from function

- Loop through the arr, check if the value at current index is same as search value return the current index,
- If none of the value matches the srchvlu then return `-1`

```js
function index(arr, srchvlu) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] === srchvlu) {  //checks current value is equal to srchvlu
      return i
    }
  }
  return -1
}

var ans = index("hello", "l");

console.log(ans);
```